# Netsuite: how to fetch info which looks like sublist in web interface, but is not listed in records browser, and most likely is not sublist at all

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

The title should describe the problem sufficiently, but what I'd like to add is that currently I'm having a specific case of this issue, but the inability to access infromation which is presented as a sublist in the webinterface, is not limited to this case, it happens quite frequently.

My current situation is this:

- I have an estimate record
- on its page there is a Relationship tab which lists contacts
  [image: screen shot of an estimate record page]

**How to find a way to access this information in SuiteScript ?**

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't simply use N/query or N/search to search for available contacts associated to the customer set on the estimate?

Comment: @SteffenAndersland no reason, I just don't know how to search for this association. On the contact record I didn't find anything appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The only supported contact relationship for `N/search` appears to be if you update the primary on the transaction you can use the join `contactprimary`. I don't see that relationship in `N/query`.

You can however create a saved search from contacts with a join on transactions. There are two transaction fields drop downs in the UI but if you construct a search that pulls data from both they appear to be the same join. The following is from loading a saved search in the console and querying its properties. This gives access to the scriptids of the fields and joins

```js
require(['N/search'], search=>{
    const srch = search.load({id:'981'}); // loaded a simple saved search
    srch.filters.forEach(f=>console.log('f: '+ JSON.stringify(f)));
    srch.columns.forEach(c=>console.log('c: '+ JSON.stringify(c)));
})
// console
    
VM7409:3 f: {"name":"numbertext","join":"transaction","operator":"haskeywords","values":["SO-00177"],"isor":false,"isnot":false,"leftparens":0,"rightparens":0}
VM7409:4 c: {"name":"entityid","label":"Name","type":"text","sortdir":"ASC"}
VM7409:4 c: {"name":"email","label":"Email","type":"email","sortdir":"NONE"}
VM7409:4 c: {"name":"phone","label":"Phone","type":"phone","sortdir":"NONE"}
VM7409:4 c: {"name":"altphone","label":"Office Phone","type":"phone","sortdir":"NONE"}
VM7409:4 c: {"name":"fax","label":"Fax","type":"text","sortdir":"NONE"}
VM7409:4 c: {"name":"company","label":"Company","type":"select","sortdir":"NONE"}
VM7409:4 c: {"name":"altemail","label":"Alt. Email","type":"email","sortdir":"NONE"}
VM7409:4 c: {"name":"tranid","join":"transaction","label":"Document Number","type":"text","sortdir":"NONE"} // from first Transaction Fields...
VM7409:4 c: {"name":"tranid","join":"transaction","label":"Document Number","type":"text","sortdir":"NONE"} // from second Transaction Fields...
```

Comment: What if I don't update _if you update the primary on the transaction_ ? Did you mean that **there is no way to use in a script the information which is visible on a web page?**

Comment: There's got to be a way to deal with these kind of situations: if information is somehow linked to a record in the web interface and it's not stored on the record (neither a field, nor a sublist), there must be a way to get this information in scripts w/o any modifications of the record

Comment: note the however in my response. You can get any contact on a transaction by `search.create({type:'contact', filters:[search.create({name:'tranid', join:'transaction'...`

Comment: When/if you have time, could you please elaborate on the example from your comment. I didn't get it. This is the first time I see a search instance ? to be used as a filter for another search. An interesting concept